# sending message to RabbitMQ using spring integration stops processing items when the app is under load

Tags: java, rabbitmq, load-testing, project-reactor, onbackpressed

I am using **projectreactor** Sinks with backPressureBuffer support to handle incoming requests in my spring boot application.
In my `FooService.kt`

```
private val requestProcessor = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer<FooRequest>(100)
```

An EmitFailureHandler as follows

```
  val emitFailureHandler = EmitFailureHandler { _: SignalType?, emitResult: EmitResult ->
    (emitResult == EmitResult.FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED || emitResult == EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW)
  }
```

I have defined an **init** method inside the class as follows:

```
  init {
    requestProcessor.asFlux()
      .flatMap { request ->
        try {
          logger.debug("handleByRabbitMq : {}", request)
          footGateway.handleByRabbitMq(request)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
          logger.error("unknown error when processing foo request", e)
          Mono.empty()
        }
      }
      .subscribe()
  }


  fun handleRequest(fooRequest: FooRequest): Mono<FooResponse> {
    val (_, id) = fooRequest
    val responseSink = Sinks.one<FooResponse>()
    responseListeners[id] = responseSink
    requestProcessor.emitNext(fooRequest, emitFailureHandler)
    return responseSink.asMono()
      .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
      .onErrorResume { Mono.just(FooResponse(REQUEST_SUBMITTED)) }
      .doOnTerminate { responseListeners.remove(id) }
  }
```

**FooController.kt**

```
  @GetMapping("/foo/request")
  @Timed(value = "foo.request")
  fun fooRequest(fooRequest: FooRequest): Mono<String> {
    return performAction(fooRequest)
      .flatMap { fooResponse ->
        Mono.fromCallable {
          "FooResponse: $fooResponse"
        }
      }
      .doOnNext { logger.debug("response {}", it) }
  }

  fun performAction(fooRequest: FooRequest): Mono<FooResponse> {
    return Mono.just(fooRequest))
      .flatMap { request ->
        fooService.handleRequest(request)
      }
      .doOnNext { response ->
        //some operations here
        logger.debug(response)
      }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
  }
```

Everything works great. The requests are emitted and processed normally initially.

**Problem**: When the app goes under a load of requests or when I do the load tesing using frameworks like `k6`, the `requestProcessor` stops emitting the items. In other words, the `init` block stops executing despite the `requestProcessor.emitNext(fooRequest, emitFailureHandler)` getting called.

Initially, the app threw `FAIL_NON_SERIALIZED` and `FAIL_OVERFLOW` error. For this, I added the above `emitFailureHandler`. It helped but postponed the issue for a few hours.

1. The App still responds though the success rate is 96%. This is still
   good.
2. The second time execution: The success rate jumps down to 88%.
   After execution of this, the app throws `503 http reponse` and no longer accepts requests.

3.logs.

[image]

[image]

[image]

New findings:
There seems to be some issues with the RabbitMQ [`fooGateway.handleByRabbitMq(request)`]. I have been digging around it but failed to see any errors. With removing the rabbitMQ in the **init** block, the app becomes responsive. Yet, I need to know the cause?

Answer (score 0):

My initial assumption was that the issue must be with the project reactor. However, the issue seems to be with `spring integration.`

The flow of requests in my application is as follows:

```
FooController (1) ➝ FooService (2) ➝ Spring Integration (3) ➝ RabbitMQ (4)
```

As explained in the question, this flow works fine for sometimes. However, after processing few requests i.e. 300 requests, the app hangs and fails to accept more requests i.e. returning `503 http reponse`.

After a through research, it seems the requests stop in step `(3)` which is delegating the tasks to spring integration for some unknown reasons.

Solution:

```
FooController (1) ➝ FooService (2) ➝ RabbitMQ (3)
```

Note: delegating the tasks to Spring Integration is convenient and recommended. So, the more ideal scenario would be as follow should the root cause get resolved with `spring integration (4)`.

```
FooController (1) ➝ Spring Integration(2) ➝ FooService (3) ➝ Spring Integration(4) ➝ RabbitMQ (5)
```